# Integrating widget into a angular app using a directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, directive

So I have currently integrated Yotpo 'reviews and comments' into my Angular application.

It consists of a javascript widget and some Html:

Js:

```
var e=document.createElement("script");

e.type="text/javascript",
e.async=true,
e.src="//staticw2.yotpo.com/API/widget.js",
e.id="test";

var t=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
t.parentNode.insertBefore(e,t);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="yotpo yotpo-main-widget"
     data-product-id="{{ product.sku }}"
     data-name="{{ product.title }}"
     data-url="{{ pageUrl }}"
    data-image-url="{{ pageImage }}"
    data-description="{{ product.description }}">
</div>
```

By placing the JS into a directive, I have got it to work, however, it will only work when you reload the page.

To try and fix this, I remove the script when the user leaves the page and reinsert the script when the user goes back into the page

Example:

```
link: function ($scope, elem) {
    elem.bind('$destroy', function() {
        var widgetScript = angular.element('#foo');
        jQuery(WidgetScript).remove();
    });

    function loadWidget() {
        var e=document.createElement("script");

        e.type="text/javascript",
        e.async=true,
        e.src="//staticw2.yotpo.com/API/widget.js",
        e.id="foo";

        var t=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        t.parentNode.insertBefore(e,t);
    }

    loadWidget();
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Not really a generic answer about loading scripts, but I made an [angular wrapper](https://gitlab.com/thelabnyc/ng-ecom-kit/tree/master/projects/ng-yotpo) around yotpo you may be interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have found a solution and thought I would post it here, as I am sure someone else will no doubt come across this issue if they are using Yotpo with Angular.

The answer is `yotpo.initWidgets();`

Unfortunately there is no information about this in Yotpo's documentations.

So this is what I have ended up doing, and it works like a charm:

```
.directive('yotpo', function ($document, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function() {

            function loadWidget() {
                var e = document.createElement("script");

                e.type = "text/javascript",
                e.async = true,
                e.src = "//staticw2.yotpo.com/API/widget.js",
                e.id = "test";

                var t = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
                t.parentNode.insertBefore(e,t);
            }

            loadWidget();

            if (typeof yotpo !== 'undefined') {
                $timeout(function () {
                    yotpo.initWidgets();
                }, 500)

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am using it with React. `yotpo.initWidgets();` is not helpful in my case. After pagination, where items are updated in the list, rating widgets do not update calling with `initWidgets()` but when I call `yotpo.refreshWidgets()` it work well. `refreshWidgets()` has another problem, as it is called from `componentDidUpdate` and we trap into loop of refreshes.

Answer (score 1):

For Yotpo's "v3" widget library / API (release late 2022) the answer appears to be calling:

```
yotpoWidgetsContainer.initWidgets()
```

Their [documentation](https://support.yotpo.com/docs/loading-yotpo-with-ajax) on this is out of date, but I was able to find a corroborating official source in their [docs on writing SPAs](https://support.yotpo.com/docs/implementing-yotpo-loyalty-referrals-modules-with-single-page-application-spa).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a directive to make this work.

The widget.js script uses the data attributes in the HTML.
You need to make sure that those data attributes are set before the javascript is loaded.

I also recommend that you'll use one-way binding for the attributes.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this as I am totally confused. Im using the directive to insert the script tag once the page loads. This is for the widget to take affect. If I just hard code  the script tag into the header of the page, the Yotpo widget wont work

Comment: Can you give me a link to your site and I will try to help.